# Why is Fringe Benefits Tax the same as the highest tier as of Income Tax

Tags: taxes, australia

In Australia FBT is currently 47%, which matches the income tax rate paid by anyone earning over $180,000 (45% income + 2% Medicare levy).

It seems like Fringe Benefits would cost more for anyone earning less than $180,000 than if their employer just paid their salary/wages - and be neutral for anyone earning over that amount.

Is there something I'm not taking into account here? If not why is FBT structured this way, and not charged at the same marginal rate as if it were income?

The only thing I could think of is to discourage companies providing any non-monetary benefits because they're harder to tax - while at the same time not outright making it illegal.

Comment: What a weird, complicated law. How does *carpe per diem* (seize the check) work in Australia?

Comment: I strongly suspect they don't want it to be a tax *loophole*. "Here, we'll pay you $15k less, but we'll rent a house for you that costs $18k and it's a win-win because the tax is lower."

Comment: I've done some more digging, it looks like in 1986 when FBT was introduced it was set to the marginal rate of average income earners. In 1991 the highest bracket was reduced to slightly more than FBT, FBT was increased to match, and it looks like both have been the same value ever since.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm guessing you meant how the tax system works. You pay 0% on the first $18,200 you earn, 19% on the next  $18,800, 32.5% on the next X amount, 37% on the next X amount, until you reach $180,000 where you pay 45%. Medicare levy is a flat 2% if you have private health insurance or earn under $90,000 - otherwise you get charged and additional 0.5% to 1.5% (scaling with income) on top. There's also payroll tax which is a % of employee wages which varies from state to state paid by the employer, that factors in FBT when calculated.

Comment: @Brett - I looked at the law and at all the modifications to it since it was enacted. It is very complex and rather convoluted. (Tax laws tend to be that way.) While the initial goal might have been, per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_benefits_tax) to help "restore equity and fairness to those employees who do not receive such benefits" (unreferenced), the goal now appears to be to continue to enrich government coffers, despite corporate schemes such as salary packing to skirt around that very high tax.

Comment: What I meant by *carpe per diem* is a US-specific concept related to fringe benefits related to jobs that require a lot of travel. Working for the US government can require a lot of traveling. The US government is the biggest renter of hotel rooms and consumer of restaurant meals. Before *per diem* was developed, one had to write extensive expense reports that accounted for all expenses. *Per diem* makes it simple: one is given an allowance for room, meals, and incidental expenses (or just meals and incidentals if the employer rents the hotel room). (continued)

Comment: Corporations demanded that they be able to use the same system; writing and processing those expense reports was very expensive. The intent was to keep travel comfortable on the employees part and less expensive on the employer's part. A side effect is that an employee who frequently travels can bring home a lot of tax-free money by staying in a somewhat seedy hotel and eating ramen cooked in the hotel's microwave.

Comment: Costs while travelling are one of the explicit exemptions - actually they're exempt from income tax as well, so if I spend money while travelling (within certain guidelines) that my employer excludes, then I'm able to claim it as a business expense when doing my taxes. If the employer reimburses the expense, then they reimburse the employee the full amount tax free since they're basically just giving you back the money you already spent - the company would then take the receipts into their records and record them as an expense. So not really a comparable system to the US.